# iOS how to show caret in custom UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a custom UIView that implements the UITextInput protocol, which included this method:

```
-(CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position;
```

Should this be sufficient to get the system API to draw the text insertion caret? Or are you supposed to draw the caret yourself?

Comment: i think you need to draw it